# Prove that the operation $*$ of a binary structure $\langle S, *\rangle$ is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

> Q: Prove that the property of an operation $*$ is commutative is indeed a structural property of a binary structure < S, * >.

---

**My attempt:**

Need to show: $\Phi(a * b) = \Phi(b * a)$.
Let $\Phi: S \to S'$ be an isomorphic mapping from the  binary structure $\langle S, * \rangle$ to the binary structure $\langle S', *' \rangle$.
Suppose $*$ is commutative.
Let $a,b \in S$ and $a', b' \in S'$.
Then, $\Phi(a) = a'$ and $\Phi(b) = b'$.
From that,

\begin{align*}
\text{LHS} &= \Phi(a * b) = \Phi(a) *' \Phi(b) = a' *' b'\\
\text{RHS} &= \Phi(b * a) = \Phi(b) *' \Phi(a) = b' *' a'
\end{align*}

---

**Issue faced:**

The issue I am facing deals with the last line from *"My attempt"* where the textbook has the answer:

> $\Phi(b * a) = \Phi(b) *' \Phi(a) = b' * a'$

It makes sense to me that if I switch $b'$ and $a'$ in that last portion, then the $*'$ appears and it would equal $a' *' b'$, which is the LHS. However, I do not understand how the $*'$ goes directly down to $*$ without changing any orders. I thought the $*'$ would stay throughout like what happened on the LHS.

---

If I could get any assistance in explaining why this is the case, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: note: Φ(b) = b'

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The question seems to be missing a lot of detail in order to make sense.

Comment: some of youre sentences did not make sense, so I rephrased them. please check this.  Your question is incomplete because not all binary operations $*$ are commutative, so please complete your question.

Comment: In addition to Tobias Kildetoft's remark, I'd like to mention that supposing that what you're trying to show holds won't prove anything.